# hyperledger fabric tutoral - write first application error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Running this lab for some people: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html When the startFabric. script runs it gets the error:

> ERROR: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest not found.

Did not see this error previous times I have run this lab. Had to go into docker-composer.yml file under /fabric-samples/basic-network directory and append a version for everywhere there is an image tag as follows: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.0.0. Did something change recently where the latest tag is not on the docker images on the public docker hub or did the docker-composer.yml change in Github?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have read following link: "[Hyperledger Fabric Samples](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html#binaries)", which has a list of required pre-requsites to run samples applications. Latest tag suppose to be `x86_64-1.0.2` and not `x86_64-1.0.0`, also if you will run following script:

`curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap-1.0.2.sh | bash`

it will publish your local docker repository with images tagged latest, hence you will be able follow the tutorial without a need to change a script. Once you will finish running the script it will list you available docker images and suppose to be similar to this:

```
===> List out hyperledger docker images
hyperledger/fabric-ca          latest              7e53be14f804        3 weeks ago         238MB
hyperledger/fabric-ca          x86_64-1.0.2        7e53be14f804        3 weeks ago         238MB
hyperledger/fabric-tools       latest              ba9750b2565d        3 weeks ago         1.33GB
hyperledger/fabric-tools       x86_64-1.0.2        ba9750b2565d        3 weeks ago         1.33GB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb     latest              3f922f54bd68        3 weeks ago         1.47GB
hyperledger/fabric-couchdb     x86_64-1.0.2        3f922f54bd68        3 weeks ago         1.47GB
hyperledger/fabric-kafka       latest              0b4b1d249e65        3 weeks ago         1.29GB
hyperledger/fabric-kafka       x86_64-1.0.2        0b4b1d249e65        3 weeks ago         1.29GB
hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper   latest              1efb063147d3        3 weeks ago         1.3GB
hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper   x86_64-1.0.2        1efb063147d3        3 weeks ago         1.3GB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer     latest              6efd17e86e65        3 weeks ago         151MB
hyperledger/fabric-orderer     x86_64-1.0.2        6efd17e86e65        3 weeks ago         151MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer        latest              0e2ed51971c9        3 weeks ago         154MB
hyperledger/fabric-peer        x86_64-1.0.2        0e2ed51971c9        3 weeks ago         154MB
hyperledger/fabric-javaenv     latest              0be45dbd7ff4        3 weeks ago         1.41GB
hyperledger/fabric-javaenv     x86_64-1.0.2        0be45dbd7ff4        3 weeks ago         1.41GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv       latest              d0f166e1a89e        3 weeks ago         1.28GB
hyperledger/fabric-ccenv       x86_64-1.0.2        d0f166e1a89e        3 weeks ago         1.28GB
```